# style = "right:0px" attribute not working in IE9?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I have made a chat application having chat window at the right side bottom corner of my screen . It remains at right side bottom corner as expected, in chrome , firefox , IE8, IE7 . But in IE9 alone , the chat window gets pushed to the left side bottom corner . I don't know the reason for this .

The chat window plugin I am using is Jquery UI chatbox plugin.
http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/chatbox.html

The code has following statement which defines position of the chat window

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-corner-top ui-chatbox" outline="0" style="right: 0px;"
```

which actually positions my chat window to this right side bottom corner .

I actually tried in developer tools chrome , and when I removed `"style="right : 0px"` It actually pushes chat window to left side bottom corner.

But I dont know why this is not working in IE9.

You can try it in IE9 by opening the link http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/chatbox.html

and clicking "Add chatbox " link in this page. you can see the chat box moving to left side bottom corner .

Comment: now you have changed the scope of a question. not fair

Comment: @diEcho Nothing changed...

Comment: For whatever reason, if you specify the `width`, it at least shows that it is being pushed to the right. It's just something else going wrong...

Comment: @Ian yup, setting `width: 208px; right: 0` does the trick for me

Comment: It seems to be that while other browsers only fill the `fixed` div up as wide as its contents, IE 9 for some reason has it behave as a div normally does - filling its parent. As Phil pointed out, if you set the width to 208px for the `ui-chatbox`, it "fixes" it. This 208 comes from the width of the `.ui-chatbox-log` and padding of the `.ui-chatbox`. I guess with `fixed` positioning, you need to be more explicit. But at the same time, I would expect it to be only as wide as its contents...IE doesn't agree.

Comment: Something even more fun that I found out. (obviously use IE 9). Add a chatbox. Use Developer Tools and inspect the chatbox stuff. Find the `textarea.ui-chatbox-input-box`. See its width as 186px? Change it. Make it 187px or whatever. Optionally, change it back. Either way, as soon as I change the width the first time, the chatbox fixes itself and is displayed as expected. I wonder if this only happens to me or is for everyone. Weird anyways.

Comment: ya , thanks , your guidance helped me ..it worked ..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding width for the container... Should work.

```
width: 205px;

<div class="ui-widget ui-corner-top ui-chatbox" outline="0" style="right: 0px; width: 205px;">
```

Comment: Hi Thanks anyway . Look at the comment thread below the question. People have given me the solution .Thanks